# Determine whether linear transformation T is one-to one and onto given matrix A representing T

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V→W$ be a linear transformation and let

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 7 & 8 \\
1 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$

be the matrix representing $T$. Determine whether $T$ is one-to one and onto

I row reduced $A$ and found it makes a diagonal matrix with the bottom row just being zeros, so the rank of $T$ (and the rank of $A$) is three. If I knew the dimension of $V$ then I could find the nullity of $T$, and if $nullity(T)=\{0\}$ then $T$ is one to one and onto... but  I don't know the dimension of $V$!

Comment: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$. If $A$ is the matrix representing $T$, then this means that for any vector $v \in V$, $T(v) = Av_{B}$, where $v_{B}$ is the column vector of elements of $F$ which expresses $v$ in coordinates with respect to the basis $B$. Then for the multiplication $Av_{B}$ to make sense, $v_{B}$ has to be a column vector with $3$ entries. This tells you that the basis $B$ must have $3$ elements, or that $\dim(V) = 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you represent a linear operator as a matrix $T $, you need a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n $ for $V $ and a basis $w_1,\ldots,w_m $ of $W $. The entries of $T $ are then the numbers such that
$$
w_k=T_{k1}v_1+\cdots +T_{kn}v_n.
$$
In your case, $V $ has dimension 3 and $W $ has dimension 4.